# SQL self join issue

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table with the following columns:

```
ID employeeID employee status  mgrID
1  amg        active           xyz
3  ccc        inactive         pqr
4  kkk        active           LLL
5  ppp        inactive         NNN
6  xyz        active           RRR
7  GGG        inactive         ccc
```

I need to get data into the below format:

```
EmployeeID, employee status, mgr ID, mgr Status where Employee ID in (amg,kkk,xyz,GGG)
```

Comment: Oh, I don't know. Mr. Nigam, the well-known Software Engineering Consultant at "SA" (whatever that might be) now has his answer. And now Mr. Shrek (the well-known green-skinned animated movie character) now knows how to do Mr. Nigam's job, while Mr. Nigam doesn't. And that seems more than fair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6932c/8/0

```
select e."employeeID", e."employee status", m."employeeID" as mgr_id, m."employee status" as mgr_status
from emp e, emp m
where m."employeeID" = e."mgrID"
and e."employeeID" in ('amg','kkk','xyz','GGG');
```

> Output

```
employeeID  employee status MGR_ID  MGR_STATUS
GGG         inactive        ccc     inactive
amg         active          xyz     active
```

Comment: Awesome! ... could you please accept the answer in that case :)

Comment: Hi Shrek, sorry to bother you but since im new here so due to some reputation mark issue, im not able to post any qq. i need you help.

I have some bulk of record 2k users with their firstname and lastname. now i need to check these users in table whethere they exit in that table or not (firstname and last name may be in any case).
please help if you have time.
thank you very much.

Comment: @amitnigam - Where are the 2k records stored? ... what are the outcomes expected if they are/are not  found in target table ?